# paramiko script works if commands are entered manually in python shell

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, ssh, paramiko

I have a simple `python` script which uses `paramiko` module to `ssh` login to a [ubuntu](/questions/tagged/ubuntu) PC and turn it off.

The problem is the script doesn't work, whereas if the commands are typed manually into the `python` interpreter, the commands work as intended, the remote PC shuts down.

here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import paramiko, subprocess
remote_ip=''
remote_user=''
remote_password=''
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(remote_ip, username = remote_user, password = remote_password,look_for_keys = False, allow_agent = False)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('sudo poweroff', get_pty = True)
stdin.write(remote_password+'\n')
stdin.flush()
ssh.close()
print(stdout.readlines())
print(stderr.readlines())
```

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: I'd suggest trying it without `get_pty = True`, since you're only running a single command, and asking for a pseudoterminal may be causing issues when your script can't make one

Comment: no i did not get any error message

Comment: But get_pty = True works when i enter the complete instruction in the python interpreter

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution, but i don't know why it works. I removed the ssh.close() line, and now the script works as intended. It will be helpful if someone could explain this.